# How do you define a class in TypeScript that implements Async Iterator with Symbol.asyncIterator?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, iterator

I've had a hard time googling for this; I want to define a class like this:

```
class MyAutoPager {

  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    // what do I put here?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, like this

```
class MyAutoPager implements AsyncIterator<number> {
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    yield 1
    await something()
    yield 2
    await somethingElse()
    yield 3
  }
}

async function main() {
  const pager = new MyAutoPager();
  for await (const x of pager) {
     console.log(x);
  }
}
```

That's it.